# How do I stop the program from overwritting existing text file

Tags: python, file-handling

I am making a game in which 2 players roll 2 dice 5 times and then the scores are saved in a file and after the game top 5 scores from the saved scores are printed.
I am trying to print the top 5 scores but my program would clear everything in the existing file and would only print the scores from the game just played.

```
file = open("Leaderboard.txt",'w')
file.write("Name        " + "Score" + "\n") #Heading
file.close()

file = open("Leaderboard.txt",'a')
file.write((player1) + ":" + (str(score1)) + "\n") #Stores Player 1's Name and Score
file.write((player2) + ":" + (str(score2)) + "\n") #Stores Player 2's Name and Score
file.close()
 
 
file = open("Leaderboard.txt",'r')
readthefile = file.readlines()
sortedData = sorted(readthefile, reverse = True)  #Sorting the Data


print(' ')
print("==============================")
print("    Top 5 Winning Scores")
print(' ')

for line in range (5):  #Outputs the Top 5 Players
    print(str(line + 1) + "\t" + str(sortedData[line]))
```

This is what it prints

```
==============================
    Top 5 Winning Scores
 
1   vedant:43
2   saiyen:37
3   Name        Score
```

It will only print the scores from this game and won't from the previous games. The error I am getting is IndexError: list index out of range

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Every time you open the file in `w` mode you wipe out the old contents.

Comment: The word you're looking for is 'append', as in 'append to the file'.

Comment: use `a` and not `w`. a == append

Comment: Ahh Thank yo sooo much! It works now (and i also feel quite stupid to not realise that)

Comment: You need to create the file (and write the header line) only when the file does not exist. If it exists, just proceed to appending.

Comment: Thanks for you help! It works now